# Convergence in Distribution and Exponential Function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

There's a well known fact that if a sequence of real numbers, $\{x_{n}\}$ converges to $x$, then:

\begin{equation*}
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{x_{n}}{n}\right)^{n} \xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty} e^{x}.
\end{equation*}

I'm wondering if the same is true for a sequence of random variables, $\{X_{n}\}$ converging in distribution to $X$, i.e.,

\begin{equation*}
\left(1+\dfrac{X_{n}}{n}\right)^{n} \xrightarrow{D} e^{X}.
\end{equation*}

Is there a theorem that would apply here (i.e. the Continuous Mapping Theorem)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is true. If we manage to show that 
$$\tag{*}  e^{X_n}-\left(1+\frac{X_n}n\right)^n\to 0\mbox{ in probability}, $$
then we conclude by the continuous mapping theorem. 
To see that (*) holds, notice that for each fixed $R$, the convergence 
$$\tag{**}  \sup_{ x\in[-R,R]}\left|e^x-\left( 1+\frac xn\right)^n\right| \to 0 $$
takes place. Then for each fixed $R$ and $\varepsilon$, 
$$\mathbb P\left\{\left|e^{X_n}-\left(1+\frac{X_n}n\right)^n\right|\gt \varepsilon\right\}\leqslant \mathbb P\left( \left\{\left|e^{X_n}-\left(1+\frac{X_n}n\right)^n\right|\gt \varepsilon\right\}\cap \{|X_n|\leqslant R\} \right) +\mathbb  P\{|X_n|\gt R\}.
$$
By (**), it follows that for each $R$ and $\varepsilon$, 
$$\limsup_{n\to \infty} \mathbb P\left\{\left|e^{X_n}-\left(1+\frac{X_n}n\right)^n\right|\gt \varepsilon\right\}\leqslant\mathbb  P\{|X_n|\gt R\}.  $$
We conclude by exploiting tightness of the sequence $(X_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$.